# Tuple to string

Tags: python

I have a tuple.

```
tst = ([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)
```

And I want to convert it to a string..

```
print tst2
"([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)"
```

what is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
tst2 = str(tst)
```

E.g.:

```
>>> tst = ([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)
>>> tst2 = str(tst)
>>> print tst2
([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)
>>> repr(tst2)
'"([[\'name\', u\'bob-21\'], [\'name\', u\'john-28\']], True)"'
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I thought of using str but never thought it woudl work!

Answer (score 4):

While I like Adam's suggestion for `str()`, I'd be leaning towards `repr()` instead, given the fact you are explicitly looking for a python-syntax-like representation of the object. Judging `help(str)`, its string conversion for a tuple might end up defined differently in future versions.

```
class str(basestring)
 |  str(object) -> string
 |
 |  Return a nice string representation of the object.
 |  If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
 ...
```

As opposed to `help(repr)`:

```
repr(...)
    repr(object) -> string

    Return the canonical string representation of the object.
    For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.
```

In todays practice and environment though, there'd be little difference between the two, so use what describes your need best - something you can feed back to `eval()`, or something meant for user consumption.

```
>>> str(tst)
"([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)"
>>> repr(tst)
"([['name', u'bob-21'], ['name', u'john-28']], True)"
```