# How do I add values within brackets into a tuple(list?) then change it to a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to add something like (0, 0) into a tuple so it would look like `((0, 0), blah, blah, ...)`
then I want to change this to a string so it would like `"((0, 0), blah, blah, ...)"`

I tried appending it to a list by letting `a = (0, 0)` then `list1.append(a)` and convert it to a string by

`string1 = ''.join(str(b) for b in list1)` but it did not work as I thought it would be.

If I do it, I'd get it like this.
`'(0, 0)(1, 1)'`.  I want it like `"((0, 0), (1, 1))"`

I'm a noob with coding and I want to learn how to do that so help would be greatly appreciated :)

+edit)
so if i had a tuple () I want to have (0, 0),(1, 1),... inside the tuple like `((0, 0), (1, 1))` then change this into a string like `"((0, 0), (1, 1))"`

Comment: Do you want a tuple `(0,0)` in a `tuple` or a string `'(0,0)'` in a `tuple`?

Comment: Could you include an example of what `list1` looks like?

Comment: Did you try `str(list1)`?

Comment: @C_Z_ list1 is basically []

Comment: @gofvonx i just edited so please have a read what I tried to talk about. sorry i can't explain things properly

Comment: @Tomerikoo Changing it to a string worked by using the join but adding the whole (0, 0) thing into a tuple or a list to have it as ((0, 0)) structure is the part that I am most wondering of.

Comment: I don't see how that relates to my comment... Please provide a clear [mre] with your requirements. From what I can understand from your question, I don't see how `str()` is not what you need. For example, doing `str(((0, 1), 2, 3))` gives `'((0, 1), 2, 3)'` which seems to be what you're looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tuple to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886669/tuple-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

First, tuples are immutable, so you cannot add anything to them. You either have to create a new tuple, or use a list instead of a tuple.

If I understand you correctly, you can do something like this:

```
t = (1, 1)
t = ((0, 0), t)
s = repr(t)      # convert to string
```